# npm install error while running docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, containers, runtime-error, npm-install

I am learning docker and I am getting this error when I run

```
npm install

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\Docker Practice\section4-react-app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Docker Practice\section4-react- 
app\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SIBA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-08T10_01_09_620Z-debug-0.log
```

This is my package.json file showing all the dependencies

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am following mosh tutorial to learn docker.

My task is to run npm install so it automatically installs all the dependencies listed in this project but I am getting above error.

Can someone help me out in this.

I know the versions may be old but it's completly fine as docker will run all the code according to the given dependencies.

So, instead of updated version, I need my application to be build with this version of software and then deploy it to docker container.

Looking forward to hear from you.

[Source code is present here](https://github.com/BCdeveloper98/Docker-Practice)

Regards,
Ali

Comment: you getting this error in docker or on your local computer ?

Comment: Yes, I am getting this error on my local computer

Comment: Could be a path error, change the directory name to 'docker-practice' to make sure its not breaking up ur build command

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] in the question itself, not behind a link?  Seeing a Windows-style host path in a Docker context doesn't look right.

Comment: @LukeCelitan I changed the name of directory to docker-practice and then I used npm i but still the same error

Comment: @DavidMaze I am running docker on windows using ubuntu 20.0 application. What exact code you need from me, I think I posted all the errors along with a list of dependencies and the command which I am running.

Comment: If you could specify what should I send you exactly, I will be greatful @DavidMaze

Comment: please include the docker commands and dockerfile portion of your trial.

Comment: @NoamYizraeli Thanks for reacching out. I was giving wrong path now everything is going fine. I just setup the right path.

Answer (score 0):

**You must run the `npm install` in the directory where package.json is located**, the error clearly states that `npm` cannot find the package.json:

> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Docker
> Practice\section4-react-  app\package.json' npm ERR!
> enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

So it must be some issue with the path.

Though to debug this error, the provided information is not enough:

1. Open up your terminal or cmd and go to the directory where package.json is located (using the `cd` command)
2. run the `ls` command, it will show all the files present in the directory
3. take the screenshot of your terminal now and post it here
4. then run `npm install` and again take a screenshot of your terminal and post it here.

Comment: Thanks @Arslan This resolved my issue. I was doing it from a different path. I just set up my path to the current working directory manually in the visual studio code terminal and it worked perfectly fine

Comment: great to hear that! if so please select the answer with the check mark and give an upvote if you think it good enough 